# How to read subarray from file using MPI using custom subarray data type?

Tags: file, fortran, mpi

I have 10 GB file and it contains data of array and I want to read subarray from the file.
I want to use MPI_File_read_at with subarray custom MPI data type.
I am new to MPI.
Do I get any benefit if I read subarray using MPI or should I use POSIX read?

```
  program read_mpi
     implicit none
     include "mpif.h"
     integer provided, ierr, psize, rank, filetype,i
     integer fh
     integer array(2,2)
     integer(kind=MPI_OFFSET_KIND) zero_off
     integer gsize(2)
     integer subsize(2)
     integer starts(2)
     integer :: status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
     gsize(1) = 4
     gsize(2) = 4
     subsize(1) = 2
     subsize(2) = 2
     starts(1) = 0
     starts(2) = 0

  call MPI_Init_thread(MPI_THREAD_SINGLE, provided, ierr)
  call MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, psize, ierr)
  call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierr)

  if(rank .eq. 1) then
    starts(1) = 2
    starts(2) = 0
    ! zero_off = 8
  endif

  if(rank .eq. 2) then
    starts(1) = 0
    starts(2) = 2
    ! zero_off = 32
  endif

  if(rank .eq. 3) then
    starts(1) = 2
    starts(2) = 2
    ! zero_off = 40
  endif

  call mpi_type_create_subarray(2, gsize, subsize, starts,
 & mpi_order_fortran, MPI_Integer, filetype, ierr)
  call mpi_type_commit(filetype,ierr)

  call MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD,"testfile",MPI_MODE_RDONLY,
 &  MPI_INFO_NULL,fh,ierr)
  
  zero_off = 0
  ! reading subarray form file with particular offset.
  call mpi_file_read_at(fh,zero_off,array(1,1),1,
 & filetype,status, ierr)

  write(*,*)array(:,:)

  call MPI_File_close(fh,ierr)
  call MPI_Finalize(ierr)
  end
```

array does not get value as expected.

testfile : 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 .....
testfile is binary file

```
od -i testfile
0000000           0           1           2           3
0000020           4           5           6           7
0000040           8           9         100         101
0000060         102         103         104         105
0000100         106         107         108         109
0000120         200         201         202         203
0000140         204         205         206         207
0000160         208         209         300         301
0000200         302         303         304         305
0000220         306         307         308         309
0000240
```

result of array 0 1 1312413 13412341

I want 0 1 4 5 for rank 0
and 2 3 6 7 for rank 1.

testfile : https://drive.google.com/file/d/16vsaBHUWu1VKw_8qR3K6XJ_ya3i0EivW/view?usp=sharing

code:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/126WyKVpixWozGKO3UPxwDXUKKmbT3rbK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please, some details. What have you tried? What have you found by searching? What is working? What is not working? What are you confused about? We'll help you if you can show what you have done, but remember this is not a code writing service.

Comment: The blanket statement is you are more likely to get better performance if you use collective I/O (e.g. `MPI_File_read_at_all()`)

Comment: Could you please post exactly the code you are using. The above fails to compile - if it is supposed to be free format all the continuation lines are wrong.

Comment: Also how much larger did you make the array, and how exactly are you running the code? How you created testfile would be very useful as well

Comment: You typically have to use the custom data type in order to set a file view.